Adding new variable to a linear regression
Let's say I have a set of $n$ features and its OLS with a given target gives weights $(\beta_i)_{i=1}^n$ and an intercept $\beta_0$. Suppose I add a new feature now and I know all possible covariances between all the features (old and new) and the target, i.e. I have an access to a square covariance matrix $C'$ with $n+2$ rows/columns, and let's say I also have the vector $\mu'$ of all the means.
Are there available formulas for how the new OLS weights $(\beta'_i)_{i=0}^{n+1}$ can be computed through the old weights, $C'$ and $\mu'$? I am not interested in expressing $\beta'$ through $C'$ - no doubts this can be done, I wonder what's the simplest way one can obtain $\beta'$ from both $C'$ and $\beta$.
To clarify: for the situation where a new feature is added in ordinary least squares regression, is there an algorithm that can use old coefficients to efficiently re-compute new coefficients?

If you know the covariances and variances I'd assume you can somehow leverage the Yule-Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem to relate the old and new weights.

Let $x_0 = \mathbf 1_{m}$ and let $x_i \in \mathbb R^m$ denote the column vector that holds the $m$ observed values of the $i$-th feature, for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n+1\}.$ Define $X \in \mathbb R^{m \times (n+1)}$ as the design matrix whose $i$-th column is given by $x_i,$ for $i \in \{0, \ldots, n\},$ and asssume $\mathop{\mathrm{rank}}(X\,|\,x_{n+1}) = n + 2.$ Further, let $P_X \mathrel{:=} XX^+$ and $P_X^\perp \mathrel{:=} I_m - P_X$ denote the projectors onto the column space of $X$ and its orthogonal complement, repectively, with $X^+ = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top.$
The two normal equations in the $(n+1)$-feature linear regression with $\mathbb E(y|X,x_{n+1}) = X\beta'+ x_{n+1}\beta'_{n+1}$ and $\beta' \mathrel{:=} (\beta'_i)_{i=0}^n$ are given by
$$
X^\top X \hat\beta' + X^\top x_{n+1} \hat\beta'_{n+1} = X^\top y, \\
x_{n+1}^\top X \hat\beta' + x_{n+1}^\top x_{n+1} \hat\beta'_{n+1} = x_{n+1}^\top y,  
$$
where $y \in \mathbb R^m$ is the response or target variable.
Writing the first equation as
$$
X^\top X \hat\beta' = X^\top (y - x_{n+1} \hat\beta'_{n+1})
$$
yields $\hat\beta' = X^+y - X^+x_{n+1}\hat\beta'_{n+1}.$
Substituting this solution for $\hat\beta'$ in the second normal equation gives
$$
x_{n+1}^\top P_X y - x_{n+1}^\top P_X x_{n+1}\hat\beta'_{n+1} + x_{n+1}^\top x_{n+1} \hat\beta'_{n+1} = x_{n+1}^\top y
$$
or
$$
x_{n+1}^\top (I_m - P_X) x_{n+1}\hat\beta'_{n+1} = x_{n+1}^\top (I_m - P_X) y,
$$
and hence
$
\hat {\beta}_{n+1}' =  (x_{n+1}^\top P_X^{\perp} x_{n+1})^{-1} x_{n+1}^\top P_X^{\perp} y.
$
Since $P_X^\perp$ is symmetric and idempotent, we also have $\hat {\beta}_{n+1}' = \left((P_X^\perp x_{n+1})^\top P_X^{\perp} x_{n+1}\right)^{-1} (P_X^\perp x_{n+1})^\top y$, showing that $\hat {\beta}_{n+1}'$ can be computed by (i) regressing $x_{n+1}$ on $X$ to obtain the residuals $P_X^\perp x_{n+1}$ and (ii) regressing $y$ on the residuals of (i). With the OLS estimate $\hat \beta = X^+ y$ from the $n$-feature linear regression already available, the OLS estimates $X^+x_{n+1}$ from step (i) and $\hat {\beta}_{n+1}'$ from step (ii) can then be used to compute $\hat \beta'.$
If several features are added, one at a time, step (i) could, e.g., be implemented by updating the QR decomposition of $(X\,|\,y)$ via Householder reflections or Givens rotations.
